# Finding 3D position of a camera used to take a 2D picture

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

Given a 3D scene and a 2D image of part of that scene, is it possible to find the position of the camera used to make the image?

Comment: When you say "Given a 3D scene", how is that 3D scene represented?  Is it a 3D model of surfaces and lights that can be rendered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume from your question that you have four points in the 2-D space whose locations you know in the 3-D space. (If your real problem is *identifying* those point, I haven't the foggiest idea where to begin.)

Your question is therefore, where can the camera be to have produced this mapping from model to image?

The camera is performing an affine transformation of the form `M x + T = y`, where `x` is a vector in 3-space representing the point in the model and `y` is the 2-space vector representing the point in the image.  Given four values for `x` and `y`, it's a straightforward matrix-arithmetic problem to solve for M and T (probably best to get MATLAB to help you here.)

Now, how do you translate M and T to position, location, and focal length of the camera?  There it gets a little hairy but [this page](http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Perspect/Perspect.htm) should help you (just remember, you are doing everything *backwards*).

Comment: The camera does not perform an affine transformation, as projecting on the sensor plane is not linear. Finding the M and T above is not solving linear equations.

Comment: @matiasg --  why is it not linear?  It _looks_ linear.

Comment: Projecting from 3D space onto the camera plane means at some moment dividing 2 of the 3 coordinates by the third one. Something like `(x, y, z) -> (x/z, y/z)`. That is not linear.

Answer (score 5):

If you take a random sampling of camera parameters, rendering the scene with each set of parameters, you can take the best matches as a starting point.  You can then perform a local optimization of the camera parameters to find those parameters which reproduce the 2D image the closest.  It isn't fast, but theoretically you could come up with very good guesses given enough time.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is tagged `computer-vision`, and applies to real-world images. If you could render the scene, you'd already know the camera position.

Comment: The OP states "Given a 3D scene".  I took that to mean that there was a model of the scene available.  If there is a model available, you can render that model from a particular viewpoint and compare the rendered result to the 2D image.

Comment: Again I reiterate my disagreement. If a model is available then as I already said, **you already know the camera position because you had to render it in the first place**. (How was the image created in the first place? It was rendered.) Even if you didn't know, you would have to perfectly render the scene, which means you need **more** than just a model. You need the exact model which was used to render the original picture. I'm not saying this isn't a reasonable answer (if you perform major optimizations AND define the needed "similarity" function), but it needs those very hefty caveats.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would assume that you know the camera position.  Whoever rendered the image would know it, but the OP didn't say that they rendered it, only that it was given.

Answer (score 3):

You need more information, but not necessary much more information.

The simplest thing to do would be to find an object or distance in the scene you know the length of (e.g. draw a virtual line in the image, say what the distance is in whatever units you want). Then you also need to know the focal length (inversely proportional to field of view angle).

Given the angle of view, a line segment (or perhaps two) with known length, you can very closely approximate the exact location of the camera with a bit of trigonometry. e.g. for a rough distance estimate:

```
   / |
  /  |
 /_d_I-segment
 \   |
  \  |
   \ |

distance "d", field of view angle "FoV"

picture.physicalsize/d == tan(FoV/2)
picture.physicalsize/segment.physicalsize == picture.pixelsize/segment.pixelsize

thus
d = segment.physicalsize*(picture.pixelsize/segment.pixelsize)/tan(FoV/2)
```

If you want even more precision, you may need more than one line segment and more careful math.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends. If the camera does not distort the image too badly, the simple trigonometry by ninjagecko might work but again depends on your application. If you want to learn how to do this in a more cleaner way and more mathematical way, check this out http://www.ces.clemson.edu/~stb/projective/.